# Adding detail in "Mask for Meta Keywords" in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a question regarding the one SEO field on Magento. Under `Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Fields Auto-Generation`.
The field `Mask for Meta Keywords` - can I add keywords after the double-bracket system generated value? Like I did in this example as per the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x3z9.png)? Does this work?

Comment: I think it is work but you can give keyword as product level also

Comment: Thanks Jinesh. Yeah we want to add at a product level as well, but wanted to add the terms that apply to all in this 'mask' section, but not sure if I added it right? Do you perhaps know?

Comment: you can add meta add product level that is standard practice